# Expiry Time of facebook access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

How do I find at what time an access token is going to expire in **php**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an API equivalent of the Facebook Access Token linter/debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236445/is-there-an-api-equivalent-of-the-facebook-access-token-linter-debugger)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The token you receive initially from Facebook in the [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) expires in 2 hours or 7200000 milliseconds or 7200 seconds. If you extend the token with the below request you will receive a new expire time of 5184000 seconds in the response which converts to 60 days. What I typically do is store this time in milliseconds added to the current Unix time in milliseconds since the epoch and continually check against that time when needed.

[Extending the token](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

As an example I would request that sources information on the client side and do the following check..

```
if (response.user.sources.FACEBOOK.expires > new Date().getTime() ) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to try to determine that?
An access token can expire if at anytime a user de-authorizes your app or changes their password.

read this
[Facebook - How-To: Handle expired access tokens](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/)

Also, I believe facebook is leading towards all apps being granted 60 day tokens.
I could be wrong, but if you enable the deprecate of offline access tokens, your ap should be granted a 60 day token. that token reups to 60 days if your user revisits your ap.